# Exception in for loop with datagridview

Tags: c#, exception, datagridview

I want to update the records present in the database after pressing a button. the records which are to be update are present in the datagridview. there are 3 rows in the datagridview. the first record gets updates successfully but when the loops repeats for the second time it shows me an exception with

> "Parameter '@p_t' has already been defined."

here is the snippet which I am using:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "update sale_order set paid_today=@p_t, balance_due=(" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value + "-" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value + ") where order_no=" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value + "";

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_t", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].FormattedValue);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        con.Close();
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cmd.Parameters.Clear();` at the end of your for loop.

From [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.clear%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

> Removes all the SqlParameter objects from the SqlParameterCollection.

Because in your second iteration, your `cmd` has already `@p_t` parameter. You need to clear your parameters in every iteration.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
   cmd.CommandText = "update sale_order set paid_today=@p_t, balance_due=(" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value + "-" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value + ") where order_no=" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value + "";
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_t", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].FormattedValue);
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   cmd.Parameters.Clear();
}
```

I don't know if there is a special reason but normally if you want to iterate all rows, you need to use `i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count` instead of `i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1`

Also parameterized your `balance_due` and `order_no` column values like you did for `paid_today` column.

Comment: once i used the same method for insertion without using cmd.parameter.clear() but in this case it did not.
can you tell me why..??

Comment: @HaiderKhattak Since I don't know your `INSERT` code but probably you might create a new `SqlCommand` instance in every iteration. Like; `for(...) { SqlComamnd cmd = new SqlCommand(); }`